# Inserir nova chave/valor em objeto

Tags: javascript

Tenho um objeto JavaScript:

```
var dict = {}
```

E preciso inserir um valor qualquer dentro dele. Tentei utilizar:

```
dict.add("chave":"valor");
```

Mas não funcionou.

Como posso fazer para adicionar uma nova chave/valor neste objeto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uma pequena alteracao

```js
var dict = {};
dict.chave ="valor";
console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade a variável `dict` não é um dicionario é um objeto javascript.

Javascript não possui dicionario, se você quer utilizar uma estrutura que guarda chave e valor você pode utilizar um [objeto javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) ou [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Com objetos você pode criar os atributos dinamicamente como já comentados nas respostas de LeAndrade e HudsonPH.

Com Map você tem vantagens com métodos `map.get(key)` que busca o valor com base na chave, `map.has(key)` verifica se há determinada chave na estrutura e `map.delete(key)` remove com base na chave.

```js
var dict = new Map();
    
// Adiciona a chave e o valor no mapa
dict.set('chave', 'valor');
console.log('Chave e valor adicionados');

// Com item inserido
console.log('has', dict.has('chave'));
console.log('get',dict.get('chave'));

console.log('Chave inexistente');
// Com um item não inserido
console.log('has', dict.has('chave inexistente'));
console.log('get', dict.get('chave inexistente'));

// Remove a chave e o valor no mapa
dict.delete('chave');
console.log('Chave e valor removida')

// Com item removido
console.log('has', dict.has('chave'));
console.log('get', dict.get('chave'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira de fazer:

```js
var dict = {};
dict['chave'] = "valor";
console.log(dict);
```